# How to draw dashed arrow?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to draw arrow like this:

[image]

I found how to draw just solid arrow [here](https://gist.github.com/mwermuth/07825df27ea28f5fc89a), but i don't know how to draw arrow like above.

**Solution:**

For me I ended up with code below:

```
func addArrowOntoView(view: UIView, startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, color: UIColor) {
    let line = UIBezierPath()
    line.moveToPoint(startPoint)
    line.addLineToPoint(endPoint)

    let arrow = UIBezierPath()

    arrow.moveToPoint(endPoint)
    arrow.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(endPoint.x - 5, endPoint.y - 4))
    arrow.moveToPoint(endPoint)
    arrow.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(endPoint.x - 5, endPoint.y + 4))
    arrow.lineCapStyle = .Square

    let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()
    sublayer.path = line.CGPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)

    //add Line
    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.path = line.CGPath
    lineLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [5, 3]
    view.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

    //add Arrow
    let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    arrowLayer.path = arrow.CGPath
    arrowLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor
    arrowLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    view.layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)
}
```

Comment: You will need to change the code to also include `CGContextSetLineDash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code for such an ArrowView that I wrote to get this in a playground:

//ArrowView

```
class ArrowView : UIView {


var dashWidth :CGFloat = 3.0
var dashGap : CGFloat = 3.0
var arrowThickNess : CGFloat = 2.0
var arrowLocationX : CGFloat = 0.0
//MARK:

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    //Compute the dashPath 

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    //Compute the mid y, path height
    let midY = CGRectGetMidY(frame)
    let pathHeight = CGRectGetHeight(frame)


    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, midY))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width - dashWidth , midY))
    path.lineWidth = arrowThickNess

    let dashes: [CGFloat] = [dashWidth, dashGap]
    path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)


    //Arrow 

    let arrow = UIBezierPath()

    arrow.lineWidth = arrowThickNess

    arrow.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + arrowLocationX , midY))
    arrow.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width -  arrowThickNess/2 - 18, 0))
    arrow.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + arrowLocationX , midY))
    arrow.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width - arrowThickNess/2 - 18 , pathHeight))
    arrow.lineCapStyle = .Square


    UIColor.whiteColor().set()
    path.stroke()
    arrow.stroke()

 }

}


let arrowView = ArrowView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 210, height: 20))
arrowView.dashGap = 10
arrowView.dashWidth = 5
arrowView.arrowLocationX = 202

arrowView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Basically you will need to create a bezier path with required line dashes and you will need to supply the dashes as an array of float values. At the end of this bezier path, you will need to draw another bezier path representing the arrow.

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Please help me to do this in UIView. I want to draw this arrow in my tableViewCell

Comment: @AndreyM. I updated the answer. Play with it in Playground and feel free to modify/extend. Extend it for support for arrow color, etc